# User registration for API/SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt, csrf, laravel-passport

I am creating an API and a separate front-end app that will consume said API. In my particular case I'm using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) for my API and some VueJS for my frontend app.

In order for a user to create an account, a user must `POST` to a route (`/oauth/token`) on the API which, requires a `client_secret` to be passed (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens).

The only options I see are:

1. Having the `client_secret` sent as a header from my frontend app. However, putting this token out in the open doesn't seem smart.
2. Don't require the `client_secret` at all. This doesn't seem much better than option 1.
3. Have a dynamic page on my frontend app that can securely store the `client_secret` and then send it to the API. While this is obviously the most secure, it seems to partially defeat the purpose of a fully static frontend (SPA).

What's the best practice for this type of approach? I've searched for how this is dealt with in general with an API and SPA, but I haven't found anything that points me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm starting to think that for registration, CSRF or other token-based protection doesn't matter. Since user registration is likely public, any protection on the client-side that's validated by the server isn't going to be very effective.

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, the Laravel Passport component seems to implement the OAuth2 Framework Protocol incorrectly.

The `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters are not part of the grant type.
For the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type, the required parameters are `username` and `password` (see [RFC6749 section 4.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2)).

`client_id` and `client_secret` are used to authenticate a confidential client that sends its credentials through the body parameters (see [RFC6749 section 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)). The Laravel Passport component should allow other client authentication schemes (especially the HTTP Basic Authentication Scheme). The RFC6749 also indicates that

> Including the client credentials in the request-body using the two
> parameters is NOT RECOMMENDED and SHOULD be limited to clients unable
> to directly utilize the HTTP Basic authentication scheme

The OpenID Connect Core specification lists some of those schemes in [its section 9](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication). The RFC6749 does not indicates how public clients (e.g. SPA) should authenticate against the token endpoint. They are supposed to use the Implicit grant type which does not require a client authentication.

Anyway, a solution could be to use a kind of proxy. This proxy has to be installed on a server. It will receive all requests from the SPA (without client secret), add the client secret and transmit the modified request to the Laravel Passport endpoint. Then the response is sent to the SPA. This way the SPA never exposes the client secret.

Comment: This solution appears the greatest from my point of view but creates a problem with Laravel Passport: the revokation of the tokens. A client can not log in from two different devices at the same time with the same password grant client because he will get disconnected (at the creation of a new token, the password grant token revokes all the other tokens from this client and user)

Comment: There is no reason for the authorization server to revoke previous access tokens because a new one is issued. This is a very bad and undesirable side effect, especially because the [RFC7009](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7009) covers that and allows the client to decide when a token should be revoked.
However, when I look at the [Passport source code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/0e8fe951996ed2a60b0b9a4012e21601a284f035/src/Passport.php#L24) the default behaviour is to keep existing access tokens. It seems that an option is available to disable that side effect

Comment: Ho! You are right, they changed their code since my last visit. They made this: https://github.com/laravel/passport/commit/b95791d42f42d405ffacdf21007f80ef7798b164 and then completely refactored the controllers, letting the phpleague do all the job. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem, and I didn't find much more documentation on the problem.

So here is what I did, that seems working great so far, you'll tell me if you see anything wrong.

For my apps, I'll be using password grant clients that I create on the fly for each "client" of my app. By client I mean browser, or mobile app, or anything.

Each browser, checks at startup if they have any client_id and client_secret into localStorage (or cookies, or anything). Then, if they don't, they call an endpoint of your API that will create a password grant client and return the information to the browser.

The browser will then be able to login the user using this new client information and his credentials.

Here is the controller I use to create a password grant client:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $hasher;

    protected $clients;

    public function __construct (Hasher $hasher, ClientRepository $clients)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
        $this->clients = $clients;
    }

    public function makeClient (Request $request)
    {
        $client = $this->clients->create(null,$request->header('User-Agent','Unknown Device'), '', false, true);

        return $client->makeVisible('secret');
    }
}
```

As you can see, as the name for the client, I try to store the User-Agent of the browser. So I can potentially display a page to my user with all his clients and giving him the right to revoke some clients like:

"Google Chrome, New York". You can also store the client IP or anything in there that will help you identify more precisely the client type of device...

Comment: Thanks, @El_Matella. Interesting approach. I guess my one question so far is: this approach doesn't really prevent anyone from seeing and making a request to the register/signup URI unfettered, correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: No you are not missing anything... I don't know how to prevent that except from trying to hide some tokens in the code, a reverse engineer will still be able to use those routes. However, with good security policy and some requests analysis, you should be able to fight this eventual traffic

Comment: Ok. I wonder if this is much worse than a traditional server-side app that uses a CSRF for one of these pages. In theory a bad actor could crawl those pages, get the CSRF and still submit unwanted requests to the backend. I'm curious to know others opinions on this.

Comment: This question interests me far too much, I started a 100 bounty on it

Comment: The solution, according to this, is to use SSR and basically treat it like a more traditional session-based application: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/ (sort of laughable)

Answer (score -1):

The simpler way would be to take care of the user registration with the Laravel app running Passport itself (and not with the frontend Vuejs app via API).
Once the user is registered and logged in, you can use Passport's `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to add a token to the user's cookie while loading up your frontend app. No more problem with client_secret.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript and https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport#super-powered-access-to-the-api-for-frontend-views

Also `oauth/token` doesn't create a user I believe? It is supposed to deliver a token (for password grant client) or an authorization code (authorization code grant client).

Comment: For this particular use case, the frontend app is a separate app from the API so this use case doesn't apply here.